How to resolve the Firebase DataConnect error about disabled "mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com" Mobile SDK API
friends. I'm trying to deploy Firebase Dataconnect with the help of Github Actions. I constantly receive the following error:
Mobile SDK API has not been used in project 989370034304 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/overview?project= then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
When I visit the URL from the error the API appears to not exist.
Here is the Github action code I'm using:
name: Staging – Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  NODE_CONFIG_ENV: staging

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Switch to Node@18
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install      
      - run: node --version
      - run: npm --version
      - run: java --version
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/setup-firebase@main
        with:
          tools-version: 13.22.0
          gcp_sa_key: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT_ID }}          
      - run: firebase --debug deploy --only storage --project project-id
      - run: firebase --debug deploy --only functions --project project-id
      - run: firebase --debug deploy --only dataconnect --project project-id

For information: I'm able to successfully deploy dataconnect to production with VC Code Extenstion and Firebase CI on my local machine.

I'm posting this as a question so that others can benefit from a workaround that I've found
Here is what I've already tried to fix the problem:

Checked and upgrade the Node, NPM, and Java versions to match the ones on my local machine.
Checked and ensured that the version of firebase-tools in Github action matches the version on my local machine
Manually analized the logs, and created a new Service Account in Google Cloud and enabled all of the roles specified in logs. These include:
Cloud Functions Admin
Cloud Run Viewer
Cloud SQL Admin
Cloud Storage for Firebase Admin
Firebase Admin
Firebase Authentication Admin
Firebase Data Connect API Admin
Firebase Hosting Admin
Service Account User
Storage Admin


It does not work because of the user of the GCP Service Account authentificaiton. Switching to Firebase CI token will resolve the problem.
Step 1. Generate Firebase CI token
firebase login:ci

Step 2. Use it in your Github Action
name: Prod – Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  NODE_CONFIG_ENV: production

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Switch to Node@18
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install      
      - run: node --version
      - run: npm --version
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/setup-firebase@main
        with:
          tools-version: 13.22.0
          firebase_token: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          #gcp_sa_key: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT_ID }} # Providing GCP Service Account Key does not work right now
      - run: firebase --debug deploy --only storage --project project-id
      - run: firebase --debug deploy --only functions --project project-id
      - run: firebase --debug deploy --only dataconnect --project project-id

